# UITableView with multiple types of cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

What is the best approch to make feed view like shown in picture ?

[image]

One approach I know is One section per post and multiple rows for internal content.

But when there is repeating content like Comments here what to do ? I am looking for better approach.

Help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `UITableView` as a subview of a `UITableViewCell`! It can get a bit hairy when creating a data source for such a thing, so it's best not to use the same ViewController as the delegate for your main table and each cells table.

Comment: Sounds interesting but won't it create problem while calculating dynamic height of cells ??

Comment: Naw, that shouldn't be too bad. For a cell's height, get its `UITableView` set up, call reloadData, then access the `contentSize` property to determine the height for the cell. You'll definitely want to cache those values. That's the all magic, no work approach. But TBH, (and I'm not a big Instagram user here so I can't say for certain) but I bet they manually calculate the height of the cells based on the amount of content they need. Picture? That's 300px. Like section? Add another 20px. Comments? 20px per comment, max 3.